# Usage of readarray and tac

Tags: io-redirection, tac

I have a file containing "lines" of text, for now only two lines.
I need to create a reversed array of these lines - FIFO style.

Using "readarray" in this fashion works fine:

```
readarray -t FileArray < "$PWD$DEBUG_DIR$DEBUG_MENU"
```

When I attempt to "reverse" the file I get gibberish:

```
readarray -t FileArray < tac "$PWD$DEBUG_DIR$DEBUG_MENU"
```

I am still learning about substitution and it is obvious  I am not using the tac command correctly. I did try different "syntax"  without success.

Comment: Related: [Bash - reverse an array](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/412868)

Comment: Yes, there are other ways to reverse the file, my question was about how to get the tac results into the array.

Comment: note that one of the answers there shows how to use `readarray` with `tac`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input redirection (as in `cat < file`) means the shell is opening the input **file** and writes its contents to the standard input of another process. 
It is not possible to just put a command after `<`.

But you can use [Process Substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) to create a file descriptor from the output of the command using the following syntax:

```
<(some_command)
```

This is similar to using output from a command like a variable using `$(some_command)`.

---

Try this:

```
readarray -t FileArray < <(tac "$PWD$DEBUG_DIR$DEBUG_MENU")
```

Comment: Thanks  works as advertized. I guess ti need to atke a closer look at file desrtiptors.

Comment: Not sure what is going on here , but this has been solved.